# How to cluster points with different images (icons)? MapBox

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox

Friends, I need to cluster points with different pictures (icons). Could you tell me by what means I can do it? How do this with the mapbox iOS SDK.

Task:
From the server I receive around 2000 images, each image corresponds to a certain coordinate. When I got their point data with an image, I'm adding a cluster to the map.

I want to see something like this on my map:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjH8l.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to cluster points with different icons - there is a library.

https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit

This proved to be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

SymbolStyleLayers can only have one image for all points.

Do you need to be able to tap these to perform an action? That only works with features added to a MGLSymbolStyleLayer, and you'll want to add them as features, not regular PointAnnotations.

If not, I would just subclass MGLPointAnnotationFeature and have an attributes item for the UIImage, and use the delegate method `imageForAnnotation` to see if the annotation is of your subclass, and, if so, return the UIImage packaged into an MGLAnnotationImage.